# Convert mixed column of unix timestamps and readable timestamps to all unix or all readable

Tags: python, pandas, unix-timestamp

I would like to harmonize a column I have with jumbled timestamps. Turn them either all to unix or readable. Please let me know if there is an easy way of doing this.

```
te[13090:13110]
13090                    1561571794
13091                    1561571957
13092                    1561572119
13093                    1561572280
13094                    1561572442
13095                    1561572606
13096                    1561572767
13097                    1561572931
13098                    1561573095
13099                    1561573258
13100                    1561573419
13101    2019-06-26 18:27:44.000000
13102    2019-06-26 18:30:36.000000
13103    2019-06-26 18:33:27.000000
13104    2019-06-26 18:36:15.000000
13105    2019-06-26 18:39:05.000000
13106    2019-06-26 18:41:52.000000
13107    2019-06-26 18:44:37.000000
13108    2019-06-26 18:47:26.000000
13109    2019-06-26 18:50:26.000000
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

A list in case you would like to recreate the problem

```
['1561571794', '1561571957', '1561572119', '1561572280', '1561572442', '1561572606', '1561572767', '1561572931', '1561573095', '1561573258', '1561573419', '2019-06-26 18:27:44.000000', '2019-06-26 18:30:36.000000', '2019-06-26 18:33:27.000000', '2019-06-26 18:36:15.000000', '2019-06-26 18:39:05.000000', '2019-06-26 18:41:52.000000', '2019-06-26 18:44:37.000000', '2019-06-26 18:47:26.000000', '2019-06-26 18:50:26.000000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You parse it twice with different formats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTimeStr': ['1561571794', '1561571957', '1561572119', '1561572280', '1561572442', '1561572606', '1561572767', '1561572931', '1561573095', '1561573258', '1561573419', '2019-06-26 18:27:44.000000', '2019-06-26 18:30:36.000000', '2019-06-26 18:33:27.000000', '2019-06-26 18:36:15.000000', '2019-06-26 18:39:05.000000', '2019-06-26 18:41:52.000000', '2019-06-26 18:44:37.000000', '2019-06-26 18:47:26.000000', '2019-06-26 18:50:26.000000']
})

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['DataTimeStr'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
idx = d1[d1.isna()].index
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[idx, 'TimeStr'].astype('int'), unit='s')

df['DateTime'] = d1.combine_first(d2)
```